# When needing to run tests from 2 classes from testng.xml, why does TestNG pick mehods randomly from classes?

Tags: testng

I need to run tests from 2 classes with TestNG.
The testng.xml configuration specifies this:

```
<classes>
    <class name="com.xyz.TestA"></class>
    <class name="com.xyz.TestB"></class>
</classes>
```

- TestA has methods: i1, i2, i3, i4
- TestB has methods: j1, j2, j3, j4

The tests run in the following sequence:

i1, i3, j1, j4, i2, i4, j2, j3

Does anybody know the reason?
Pls kindly help~
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest TestNG, use "preserve-order":

```
<test name="foo" preserve-order="true">
  <classes>
    <class...>
```

Comment: will the order depend on the order they are discovered?