# Why @AfterClass called after tests from another classes?

Tags: testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I tried to run test cases in determined order but without luck. As I see methods annotated with `@AfterClass` runs after methods from another test:

```
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@558ee9d6
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.beforeClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.someCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.beforeClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.someCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.anotherCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.afterClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.anotherCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.afterClass()
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.25 sec
```

And it fail because all `@Test` from `ITCaseTwo` must be called only after `ITCaseOne.afterClass()` (because I use Selenium and tests from one case should check appropriate page).

My simple classes:

```
public class ITCaseOne {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.beforeClass()\n", getClass());
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterClass() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.afterClass()\n", getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "std-one")
    public void someCase() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.someCase()\n", getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "logic-one", dependsOnGroups = "std-one")
    public void anotherCase() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.anotherCase()\n", getClass());
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ITCaseTwo {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.beforeClass()\n", getClass());
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterClass() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.afterClass()\n", getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "std-two")
    public void someCase() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.someCase()\n", getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "logic-two", dependsOnGroups = "std-two")
    public void anotherCase() {
        System.out.printf("RUN %s.anotherCase()\n", getClass());
    }

}
```

If it's important I use `maven-failsafe-plugin` 2.12 and `testng` 6.4

(BTW, I also try to use suite file with `preserve-order="true"` but it doesn't work for me.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this behavior, it's a bug. I'll look into it. In the meantime, commenting out one of the two dependsOnGroups should fix the incorrect behavior.

Comment: Yes, it works only when I commented out *both* `dependsOnGroups` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you have dependent method requirements.  If you are keeping them in separate classes, then you can make @Test of the second class, which you want executed second, to depend on one of the **groups in the first class**.
So if you keep 
@Test(groups = "std-two", dependsOnGroups = "logic-one"), things should work, the way u want it..

Comment: Oops. I've just fixed typo in my question to clarify what I expect. I need to execute all methods from second class only after all methods from first class.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. But it has some downside: all classes should be chained by this way and when one of tests in first test case fail all others will be skipped. Also this solution adds strict order for tests execution, but in reality I don't care who will be called first -- `ITCaseOne` or `ITCaseTwo`.

Answer (score 1):

I found yet another way how to fix it with test suite and `preserve-order="true"` (inspired by [When needing to run tests from 2 classes from testng.xml, why does TestNG pick mehods randomly from classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723970/when-need-to-run-tests-from-2-classes-from-testng-xml-why-the-testng-pick-mehod)).

Create `src/test/config/testng.xml` with following content

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Selenium tests" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Test #1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.testng.ITCaseOne" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test #2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Handle it by `maven-failsafe-plugin`

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/src/test/config/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And now it works as expected:

```
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.beforeClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.someCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.anotherCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseOne.afterClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.beforeClass()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.someCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.anotherCase()
RUN class com.example.testng.ITCaseTwo.afterClass()
```